# ThreeJS hide texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can i hide texture on threejs objects? I could not find anywhere. I don't want to remove texture. is it possible ?

```
const texture = new THREE.Texture(this.setTexture(properties));
 object.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          map:texture,
          color,
          side: THREE.DoubleSide,
          shininess: 30,
          flatShading: THREE.FlatShading,
          transparent: false,
          opacity: Number(opacity)
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to hide a texture or make it invisible. You have to remove the texture from the material like so:

```
object.material.map = null; 
object.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

`three.js R110`